# Use same controller on multiple models

Tags: c#, api, generics, controller

In an NHibernate .Net Framework using .net Core API project i have 10 models, which on saving uses the same function

```
 public static void Save(object saveEntity, ISession session)
 {
    session.BeginTransaction();
    session.Save(saveEntity);
    session.FlushMode = NHibernate.FlushMode.Commit;
    session.Transaction.Commit();
    session.Flush();
 }
```

For now I have made 10 controllers which have the same structure and returns the saved model

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult<ModelName> Post([FromBody]ModelName saveItem)
 {
    if (saveItem.ID == 0)
        Core.DataStore.Repository.Default.Save(saveItem, _session);
    else
        Core.DataStore.Repository.Default.Update(saveItem,_session);
    return saveItem;
 }
```

The call to the API is done like:

```
    public static async Task<ModelName> Save(ModelName saveItem)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveItem), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var response = await client.PostAsync("api/<<ModelName>>/", content).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                var stringResult = (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                ModelName result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelName>(stringResult);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I could make one Controller + function to call the controller which consumes a generic T

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the controller discovery mechanism to achieve this.
This can be done by implementing the `IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>` and having a generic controller.

An example on how to implement this can be found here https://www.strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: Thx alot - I take a look at the example.